# Javascript / jQuery - How to keep 2 states of the same variable over time

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, time, cycle

My question is both logical and javascript related.

My goal is to feed a [**jquery counter**](http://sophilabs.github.com/jquery-counter/) with **two states of the same variable over time**, so that every x seconds it increases from the start state to the end state.

At the end of the cycle, I want to make the end state the next start state, and so on...

Note that I retrieve the variable value from a php file.
(edit)The variables are declared outside of the function:

```
var $publishersCurvalue,
    $minTime,
    ...
```

Here is my Counter. It refreshes itself every 5s. The result, since I'm only using one variable state (**$publishersCurvalue**), is that it jump from the previous state to the new one.

How can I get both the previous value and the new one at every cycle ?
I've tried several technics, but no luck so far.

My intent is to trigger the incrementation animation that occurs when the counter reads two different values.

```
var $i = 0;
function publisherCounter() {
    $.getJSON("counter.php?t=p", function(result) {
        // defalut values
        $minTime                      = result[0].minTime;
        $max                          = result[0].max;
        $curTime                      = result[0].curTime;

        // current value
        $publishersCurvalue           = result[0].curValue;

        // Publishers values
        $publisherMinResult           = result[0].min;
        $publisherIncPerDay           = result[0].incPerDay;

        // frequency
        $publisherIncPerDayResultTemp = parseInt((($curTime - $minTime)/86400) * $publisherIncPerDay);
        $publisherIncPerDayResult     = parseInt(86400/$publisherIncPerDayResultTemp);

        $('#counter_publishers').addClass('counter-analog').counter({
            initial: $publishersCurvalue,
            direction: 'up',
            interval: 1,
            format: '9999999',
            stop: $publishersCurvalue
        });

    });
    $i++;
};
setInterval(publisherCounter, 5000);
publisherCounter();
```

Comment: Why not `oldvalue=$publishersCurvalue` and then `$publishersCurvalue           = result[0].curValue` ? Note that you are using global variables, you should put `var` before assigning it when is not used outside that block. Moreover, `$` is not necessary in variable names unlike PHP, and is used mostly for jQuery related values.

Comment: likely have to modify plugin since there will be no way to know last value when your ajax occurs without being able to track it from within plugin

Answer (score 0):

Change `$publishersCurvalue` from a simple variable into an object with two properties:

```
// wherever you declare it...
var $publishersCurvalue = {
    prev: 0,
    cur: 0
};

...

// current value
$publishersCurvalue.cur = result[0].curValue;

...

$('#counter_publishers').addClass('counter-analog').counter({
    initial: $publishersCurvalue.prev,
    direction: 'up',
    interval: 1,
    format: '9999999',
    stop: $publishersCurvalue.cur
});
```

I don't really understand your intent so you may need to change up your usage of `prev` and `cur`.

Comment: My intent is to see the counter incrementation animation between the two values.